# How do I make docker-compose reuse previous volumes for a service running postgres?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am using Windows 10 with WSL2. I'm running docker-compose through Visual Studio 2022.

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dbService:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
        - PostgresUsers:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
        - dbService

volumes:
    PostgresUsers:
```

If I create tables and insert data into a created database in my postgres service, shutdown and delete the 2 running containers, and create them again, no data is persisting. Put another way, when I register a Server and check the Databases in that server in pgAdmin, none of the previously entered data is present.

I've checked my Docker volumes directory in the hidden wsl$ drive here:

`\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes`

and am seeing that each time I run docker-compose through Visual Studio, new volumes that are not the name I specified are being created, ones that appear to have a random string of what I'm assuming is the Docker Container's ID or some other related value

How can I make data entered in Postgres persist after shutting down and deleting the running containers?

Comment: Seems like it might have something to do with your system.  I tried launching, destroying, and re-launching with `docker-compose up/down` with your `.yaml` file above and the data persisted. (I ran it on a Mac, though)

Comment: @richyen Thanks, it's definitely something to do with Windows and WSL2. The solution ended up being to change the specified volume to `./PostgresUsers:/var/lib/postgresql/data` instead of `PostgresUsers:/var/lib/postgresql/data` .